# Getting PayPal Access Token with RestSharp returning "Status Code: NotFound"

Tags: c#, paypal, restsharp

Getting PayPal Access Token not working

I'm getting the response:

> "StatusCode: NotFound, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 131)"

My code, using RestSharp

```
public void getToken()
{
    var clientId = "{client-ID}";
    var secret = "{client-secret}";

    if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol != SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // forced to modern day SSL protocols
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token") { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
    var authRequest = new RestRequest("oauth2/token", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientId, secret);
    authRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token&refresh_token={refresh_token}");
    var authResponse = client.Execute(authRequest);
}
```

I do have a slight feeling my `grant_type` may be incorrect, as I'm not 100% sure what actually goes here, after a bit of research it still isn't clear to me - but I went with `refresh_token&refresh_token={refresh_token}`. Although `{refresh_token}` is static, I'm not sure if you're supposed to populate this with a value, or how to do so.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong - and if my suspicions regarding the issue being the `grant_type` being correct?

Answer (score 2):

You've doubled up the path.

```
new RestClient("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token")
```

This line sets that URL as the *base address*, which is prepended to your other path strings.  So, when you use  `new RestRequest("oauth2/token", ...)`, the URL you end up fetching is

```
https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/oauth2/token
```

Just remove the path string from the base address, so you have:

```
 new RestClient("https://api.paypal.com/v1")
```

Comment: Seems like a stupid question, but wouldn't it then need to be new `RestRequest("v1/oauth2/token", ...)`? Without v1, it gives me a 0 statuscode, without it, the statuscode is "badrequest".

Comment: @MattHodson You're right, I didn't mean to remove the v1.  Sorry about that, I took just a bit too much off.  You can add the v1 to either path string.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above but have tidied the answer up a little

```
public string GetAccessToken()
{
  var clientId = "my_client_id";
  var secret = "my_password";

  var client = new RestClient("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/") { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
  var authRequest = new RestRequest("v1/oauth2/token", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
  client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientId, secret);

  authRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
  var response = client.Execute(authRequest);

  AccessToken token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessToken>(response.Content);
  return token.access_token;
}




public class AccessToken
 {

    public string scope { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string app_id { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string nonce { get; set; }

  }
```